# Concurrency & Parallelism in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am learning app-engine and have created a spring based application which has a controller for accepting all in-coming requests. There is just one method in the controller which will be used to populated 5 tables in BigQuery. So, I have 5 separate methods to insert data in BigQuery. I am calling each of these methods one at a time sequentially in my controller method. But, I want to execute these 5 BQ methods in parallel not in sequence. How can I achieve such a parallelism in App-Engine app.

Comment: look into task queues, or just doing urlFetch to itself which would trigger the appengine autoscaler or create new threads automatically on existing instances. adding as comment only as question is a little broad.

Comment: if you want to do that from same request, use Threads and ThreadManager

Comment: Generally using threads in a front facing request is not recommended.  You should generally consider using async methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a two different strategies you can use on GAE - concurrency and deferred approaches. Both have a few flavours.

### Concurrency

There are two basic flavours of this, relying on async APIs or creating background threads.

Most of the GAE platform APIs are *asynchronous* (or can be) and you can invoke multiple of them at once then block until they've all resolved. In this case, you could make 5 asynchronous calls to BigQuery using the UrlFetchService.

GAE also allows the creation of *background threads* for the duration of a request. All threads must complete before the result is returned to the client. This is generally the least idiomatic approach for GAE.

### Deferred processing

GAE offers two flavours of task queue, push and pull.

*Push queues* are basically a queued task being executed by a specified URL at a rate you control. They can participate in transactions and have retry rules etc. they can be used to ensure a workload is executed but independently of the initiating request. This is the most idiomatic solution for the general problem of 'background work' on GAE

*Pull queues* are queues that wait for an initiating request to slurp some data out for processing, usually in bulk. They're triggered by cron jobs typically.

In your case, your best bet is to use async http requests, unless you're using an SDK/API wrapper that doesn't expose this. If not, look to task queues. Almost any app you build will end up using them anyway, and they're very graceful and simple to comprehend.